# ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')

Tags: python, dataframe

I am pretty new to python, so I am really sorry in advance about asking probably an easy question. I am trying to find return customers in my dataset. This is my approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta


data = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.index = data['date']
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
for a in data.index:
    date_mask = (data.index >a) & (data.index < a+timedelta(days=60))
    s=data['customer'][date_mask]
    val=data.loc[a,'customer']
    print(val in s.unique(),a)
```

I am getting this error:

> File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/testproj/venv/Lib/site-packages/pandas/core/dimatest2.py", line 31, in 
>       print(val in s.unique(),a)
>
> File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\testproj\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1745, in wrapper
>       raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
>   ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

A weird thing is that the code works for data in the whole first month. I will really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Can you share content of `abc.csv`?

Comment: This is transactions dataset with 3 columns: 
'date' - date and time of the order
'customer'-customer id
'order' - order id

Comment: Please do not describe data format but show it.